# What is the difference between a KeySpace and a KeySpaceDefinition in Hector?

Tags: c#, java, cassandra, hector

I'm relatively new to the world of Hector and Cassandra.

I'm familiar with the concepts of `KeySpaces` and `ColumnFamilies`.

What is the difference between the `KeySpace` and the `KeySpaceDefinition` types?

Are they interchangeable?

Two methods are exposed via the Factory:

`CreateKeySpace()`and `CreateKeyspaceDefinition()`.

What is the difference between these two calls and when would I use them?

If I want to execute a CQL query, I need to use a `KeySpace`.

```
CqlQuery cq = new CqlQuery(keySpace, .., .., ..)
```

How do I retrieve an existing `KeySpace` from a cluster?

Answer (score 3):

The Hector documentation is ... quite horrible if you're new to Cassandra…

A `KeyspaceDefinition` describes a key space within Cassandra, while a `Keyspace` is an object that refers to an existing key space, allowing you to specify what key space Hector should issue a request to.

You'll probably only need a `KeyspaceDefinition` when creating a new one or retrieving information on a key space. You'll need a `Keyspace` object every time you execute any kind of request (mutate / query).

Retrieving an existing key space is done using `HFactory.createKeyspace(String, Cluster)`. Note that that does not actually *create* a key space in Cassandra, it just creates an object for Hector. Creating an actual key space is done by `cluster.addKeyspace(KeyspaceDefinition)`.